# Calculus-derivative by using two ways but got two different answers

Tags: calculus

[image]

[image]

Curious why the answer are not the same? ....the sign...but I checked them again and again....no clue

Comment: The second one should be with $(x+h)$ not $(x-h)$.

Comment: Notice you just ended up with the negative of the derivative. It's the slope if you were heading in the opposite direction

Comment: Oh! Many thanks!!! Gotcha!!

Comment: Thank Vadim123 & jameselmore so much:)